# Overriding data.table key order causes incorrect merge results

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

In the following example I use a `dplyr::arrange` on a `data.table` with a key. This overrides the sort on that column:

```
x <- data.table(a = sample(1000:1100), b = sample(c("A", NA, "B", "C", "D"), replace = TRUE), c = letters)
setkey(x, "a")

# lose order on datatable key
x <- dplyr::arrange(x, b)

y <- data.table(a = sample(1000:1100), f = c(letters, NA), g = c("AA", "BB", NA, NA, NA, NA))
setkey(y, "a")

res <- merge(x, y, by = c("a"), all.x = TRUE)
# try merge with key removed
res2 <- merge(x %>% as.data.frame() %>% as.data.table(), y, by = c("a"), all.x = TRUE)

# merge results are inconsistent
identical(res, res2)
```

I can see that if I ordered with `x <- x[order(b)]`, I would maintain the sort on the key and the results would be consistent.

I am not sure why I cannot use `dplyr::arrange` and what relationship the sort key has with the merge. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I have any insights, but if you change your first merge to `res<-merge(x[,a:=as.integer(a)], y, by=c("a"), all.x=T)`, you will find that res and res2 are identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with `dplyr::arrange(x, b)` you do not remove the `sorted` attribute from your `data.table` contrary to using `x <- x[order(b)]` or `setorder(x, "b")`.

The `data.table` way would be to use `setorder` in the first place e.g.

```r
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(a = sample(1000:1100), b = sample(c("A", NA, "B", "C", "D"), replace = TRUE), c = letters)
setorder(x, "b", "a", na.last=TRUE)
```

The wrong results of joins on `data.table`s which have a `key` although they are not sorted by it, is a known bug (see also [#5361](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5361) in `data.table` bug tracker).

Comment: Could you post a reference for the bug? I'm having trouble finding a relevant open issue on the `data.table` GitHub reop.

Comment: @v44k3 I added the issue to the answer. Your issue is not the same as the one there but it boils down to having a `data.table` with a `key` which isn't actually sorted by this key.